# Getting data In AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

i have a button and in the button click i wanted to get a JSON data using AJAX call,here is the code which i tried in button click.But its not working

```
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var request = $.ajax({

            url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/iata/SAN?appId=952b68c2&appKey=9d5a372da9f88679ac97a60c1e0c58f9',
            type: 'POST',
            //data: $("#ganttForm").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            accepts: {
                json: "application/json"
            },
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },

            success: function (data) {
                alert('success')
                var data1 = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(data1);
                //console.log(window.JSON.parse(data));
                //alert(obj.ganttdata) 
                //console.log($.parseJSON(data.d));
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(data1));
                createEmptyGanttChart1(data1);

            },

            complete: function () {
                alert('complete')
                //  console.log('complete 1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert('failure')
                //  console.log('complete 1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: im not getting the JSON data

Comment: Is `https://api.flightstats.com` the same domain that your page is from?

Comment: You should use GET rather than POST

Comment: @nnnnnn... no its different

Comment: Well there's your problem. You can't do a cross-domain Ajax request.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan... can u please rewrite the code?

Comment: @AnilkumarM Use GET rather than POST

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a cross-domain Ajax request, which doesn't work because it violates the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

However, the api.flightstats.com site does appear to support jsonp - at least, when I modified your URL to this:

```
https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/jsonp/iata/SAN?appId=952b68c2&appKey=9d5a372da9f88679ac97a60c1e0c58f9
// Note the "p" that I've added here -----------------^
```

...it returned a response in jsonp format. So try this code instead:

```
    var request = $.ajax({

        url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/jsonp/iata/SAN?appId=952b68c2&appKey=9d5a372da9f88679ac97a60c1e0c58f9',
        type: 'POST',
        //data: $("#ganttForm").serialize(),
        dataType: 'jsonp',   // NOTE the type is 'jsonp' not 'json'

        success: function (data) {
            alert('success')
            alert(data);
            createEmptyGanttChart1(data);  // NOTE no need to parse data

        },

        complete: function () {
            alert('complete')
            //  console.log('complete 1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert('failure')
            //  console.log('complete 1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
        }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8H8/

Note that there is no need to use `$.parseJSON(data)` because jQuery automatically parses the response for you and `data` will already be an object.

Comment: @AnilkumarM - I've provided a working demo with the code I've shown. When you say "not working" do you mean that your success function isn't called, or...?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan... nop... code is perfect..i think issue in parsing the URL

Comment: success function is not calling

Comment: Does my fiddle demo work for you? If so, start with just the code I've shown on your own page and see if you get the alerts then...

Comment: @nnnnnn fiddle demo is working in my browser.but when i copy paste the ditto code in my project,its not working.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

change this

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```